# JavaScript variable is undefined even after assigning an object property method

Tags: javascript

In the following code when I execute trace function and the variable "original" gets assigned to o[m] which is undefined initially but once I define o[m] as a nested function inside trace and trace function returns I expect that value of "original" variable should be newly defined nested function but to my surprise it is still undefined. I can't understand why?

```
   var o = {};            
   function trace(o, m) {
   var original = o[m]; 
   o[m] = function () { 
    alert(new Date(), "Exiting:", m);
    var result = original.apply(this, arguments); 
    alert(new Date(), "Exiting:", m); 
    alert(result); 
 };
}

 trace(o, "m");
 o.m("My JavaScript");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Identifiers don't update when you change the source you used to set them.

```
var o = {prop: function () {return 'old ref';}};
var foo = o.prop; // foo() === "old ref"
o.prop = function () {return 'new ref';};
foo(); // "old ref"
```

---

However, it may also be worth noticing

```
var e = o; // o as before
o.prop = function () {return 'even newer ref';};
e.prop(); // "even newer ref"
e === o; // true
```

When the identifier references an *Object* it's referencing the same object and not a copy, so changes made to it effect them all. This is because you're accessing the *Object* with the identifier rather than the property of that *Object*, i.e. `e === o`

If you were to then do `o = fizz`, `o` now points to a different thing to `e` so `e !== o`

```
var fizz = {buzz: "I'm something new!"};
o = fizz;
e.buzz; // undefined, e points at {prop: function () {...}}, not fizz
o.prop(); // TypeError, o points at fizz, not e
o.buzz; // "I'm something new!"
e === o; // false
fizz === o; // true
```

---

Lastly, by looking over what you were attempting to do you may need to consider "was there anything before?". This is why your code is throwing an *Error* currently.

```
function change(obj, prop, echo) {
    var prev_method = obj[prop];
    obj[prop] = function () {
        if (prev_method) // only if we had something before
            prev_method.apply(this, arguments); // try to invoke it
        console.log(echo);
    };
}

var o = {};
change(o, 'spell', 'H');
change(o, 'spell', 'e');
change(o, 'spell', 'l');
change(o, 'spell', 'l');
change(o, 'spell', 'o');

o['spell'](); // returns undefined, logs H, e, l, l, o
```

Comment: Got you sir , I would remember it as a rule of thumb that in JS identifiers don't update.

Comment: Can you please elaborate o = fizz a little bit more in terms of some code ?Thanks for all the help

Comment: @user2913184 if you did `e = o` (after `o = fizz`) **or** `e = fizz` you would then have all 3 pointing to the same thing. It's just you have to update each identifier manually. Also, `e.prop()` should never throw an error in the code I've written. **`o.prop()`** throws an error in the section about `fizz`.